# Conversion from int to char failed and console prints weird symbol

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, int

I am having a weird issue and I don't know how to explain it. When I run this code it prints this symbol -> .
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
     int num = 1;
     char number = num;

     std::cout<<number<<std::endl;

     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why. Normally it should convert the integer to char. I am using Dev C++ and my language standard is ISO C++11. I am programming for 4 years now and this is the first time I get something like this. I hope I explained my issue and if someone can help me I will be grateful.

[image]

Comment: Try this: `std::cout<<+number<<std::endl;`

Comment: It fixed it. Thank you. But why It didn't work before? Could you explain, please?

Comment: The weird symbol is the character with ASCII code `1`. What did you want to print? If you wanted to print the text `1`, then just do `std::cout << num;` Why did you want to convert to `char` in the first place?

Comment: Because printing a `char` prints the character, not the encoding value in decimal. The character with an encoding value of 1 likely isn't printable.

Comment: I wanted to print 1 as a char.

Comment: What is "1 as a char"? Is it a character with encoding value 1? Or is it a character containing the digit 1? `1 != '1'`.

Comment: In case you are wondering, `+number` converts the char to `int`, putting you right back where you started.

Comment: I am working on a project and I needed to convert int to char and I got this weird symbol. I tested it on this small code.

Comment: A value of an `int` variable might not be representable by a single character. In that project, is your `int` guaranteed to be between 0 and 9? If so, `char number = '0' + num;`

Comment: Yes, It will always be number.

Comment: As a note, `char` is really just a byte-sized integer with the special distinction of also being the designated storage type for integers representing "narrow" characters (ASCII, UTF-8 code points prior to C++20, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Conversion from int to char failed

Actually, int was successfully converted to char.

> Normally it should convert the integer to char.

That's what it did. The result of the conversion is char with the value 1.

Computers use a "character encoding". Each symbol that you see on the screen is encoded as a number. For example (assuming ASCII or compatible encoding) the value of 'a' character is 97.

A char with value of 1 is not the same as char with the value that encodes the character '1'. As such, when you print a character with value 1, you don't see the number 1, but the character that the value 1 encodes. In the ASCII and compatible encodings, 1 encodes a non-visible symbol "start of heading".

---

> I wanted to print 1 as a char.

You can do it like this:

```
std::cout << '1' << '\n';
```

Comment: This code was just for testing purposes. I am working on project and I needed to convert int to char. I looked online and I read that If I type char a = '1'; it will accept it and automatically convert the number to char. And when I tested it I got that symbol. That's why I made this small code for testing.

Comment: @Vektor007 a `char` pretty much **is** a number. When you print `char a='1'` you indeed get what you expect, but again you made the mistake to assume that would be somehow equal to `char a=(char) 1`, which it is not (the latter is "start of heading"). Actually, the second statement doesn't make much sense. Note: `'1'==49` and `1=='SOH'`

Answer (score 0):

Then, since 4 years you seem to misunderstand what `char` is. It's not directly a character, but a number. It's the **encoding** that turns that number into a readable character.

Essentially, `char i=1` is not the same as `char i='1'` ([ascii table](http://asciitable.com)).